# Inserting cells inside database Laravel PHP

Tags: php, laravel

I have this code I want to save the records to the database so far I have this but I don't know how to continue

```html
<table class="table table-bordered table-responsive-xs">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">#</th>
      <th scope="col">You</th>
      <th scope="col"> >Partner</th>
      <th scope="col">Kid1</th>
      <th scope="col">Kid2</th>
      <th scope="col">Kid3</th>
      <th scope="col">Kid4</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row"><input type="hidden" name="rows[]" value="Birthday">Birthday</th>
      <td><input type="hidden" name="label_id[]" value="1"><input type="text" name="matchtext[]" style="width: 80px;"></td>
      <td><input type="hidden" name="label_id[]" value="1"><input type="text" name="matchtext[]" style="width: 80px;"></td>
      <td><input type="hidden" name="label_id[]" value="1"><input type="text" name="matchtext[]" style="width: 80px;"></td>
      <td><input type="hidden" name="label_id[]" value="1"><input type="text" name="matchtext[]" style="width: 80px;"></td>
      <td><input type="hidden" name="label_id[]" value="1"><input type="text" name="matchtext[]" style="width: 80px;"></td>
      <td><input type="hidden" name="label_id[]" value="1"><input type="text" name="matchtext[]" style="width: 80px;"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row"><input type="hidden" name="rows[]" value="heutige Text2">Text2</th>
      <td><input type="hidden" name="label_id[]" value="2"><input type="text" name="matchtext[]" style="width: 80px;"></td>
      <td><input type="hidden" name="label_id[]" value="2"><input type="text" name="matchtext[]" style="width: 80px;"></td>
      <td><input type="hidden" name="label_id[]" value="2"><input type="text" name="matchtext[]" style="width: 80px;"></td>
      <td><input type="hidden" name="label_id[]" value="2"><input type="text" name="matchtext[]" style="width: 80px;"></td>
      <td><input type="hidden" name="label_id[]" value="2"><input type="text" name="matchtext[]" style="width: 80px;"></td>
      <td><input type="hidden" name="label_id[]" value="2"><input type="text" name="matchtext[]" style="width: 80px;"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row"><input type="hidden" name="rows[]" value="Text3">Text3</th>
      <td><input type="hidden" name="label_id[]" value="3"><input type="text" name="matchtext[]" style="width: 80px;"></td>
      <td><input type="hidden" name="label_id[]" value="3"><input type="text" name="matchtext[]" style="width: 80px;"></td>
      <td><input type="hidden" name="label_id[]" value="3"><input type="text" name="matchtext[]" style="width: 80px;"></td>
      <td><input type="hidden" name="label_id[]" value="3"><input type="text" name="matchtext[]" style="width: 80px;"></td>
      <td><input type="hidden" name="label_id[]" value="3"><input type="text" name="matchtext[]" style="width: 80px;"></td>
      <td><input type="hidden" name="label_id[]" value="3"><input type="text" name="matchtext[]" style="width: 80px;"></td>
    </tr>
    <th scope="row"><input type="hidden" name="rows[]" value="Text4">Text4</th>
    <td><input type="hidden" name="label_id[]" value="4"><input type="text" name="matchtext[]" style="width: 80px;"></td>
    <td><input type="hidden" name="label_id[]" value="4"><input type="text" name="matchtext[]" style="width: 80px;"></td>
    <td><input type="hidden" name="label_id[]" value="4"><input type="text" name="matchtext[]" style="width: 80px;"></td>
    <td><input type="hidden" name="label_id[]" value="4"><input type="text" name="matchtext[]" style="width: 80px;"></td>
    <td><input type="hidden" name="label_id[]" value="4"><input type="text" name="matchtext[]" style="width: 80px;"></td>
    <td><input type="hidden" name="label_id[]" value="4"><input type="text" name="matchtext[]" style="width: 80px;"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row"><input type="hidden" name="rows[]" value="Text5">Text5</th>

      <td><input type="hidden" name="label_id[]" value="5"><input type="text" name="matchtext[]" style="width: 80px;"></td>
      <td><input type="hidden" name="label_id[]" value="5"><input type="text" name="matchtext[]" style="width: 80px;"></td>
      <td><input type="hidden" name="label_id[]" value="5"><input type="text" name="matchtext[]" style="width: 80px;"></td>
      <td><input type="hidden" name="label_id[]" value="5"><input type="text" name="matchtext[]" style="width: 80px;"></td>
      <td><input type="hidden" name="label_id[]" value="5"><input type="text" name="matchtext[]" style="width: 80px;"></td>
      <td><input type="hidden" name="label_id[]" value="5"><input type="text" name="matchtext[]" style="width: 80px;"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row"><input type="hidden" name="rows[]" value="Text6">Text6</th>
      <td><input type="hidden" name="label_id[]" value="6"><input type="text" name="matchtext[]" style="width: 80px;"></td>
      <td><input type="hidden" name="label_id[]" value="6"><input type="text" name="matchtext[]" style="width: 80px;"></td>
      <td><input type="hidden" name="label_id[]" value="6"><input type="text" name="matchtext[]" style="width: 80px;"></td>
      <td><input type="hidden" name="label_id[]" value="6"><input type="text" name="matchtext[]" style="width: 80px;"></td>
      <td><input type="hidden" name="label_id[]" value="6"><input type="text" name="matchtext[]" style="width: 80px;"></td>
      <td><input type="hidden" name="label_id[]" value="6"><input type="text" name="matchtext[]" style="width: 80px;"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row"><input type="hidden" name="rows[]" value="Text7">Text7</th>
      <td><input type="hidden" name="label_id[]" value="7"><input type="text" name="matchtext[]" style="width: 80px;"></td>
      <td><input type="hidden" name="label_id[]" value="7"><input type="text" name="matchtext[]" style="width: 80px;"></td>
      <td><input type="hidden" name="label_id[]" value="7"><input type="text" name="matchtext[]" style="width: 80px;"></td>
      <td><input type="hidden" name="label_id[]" value="7"><input type="text" name="matchtext[]" style="width: 80px;"></td>
      <td><input type="hidden" name="label_id[]" value="7"><input type="text" name="matchtext[]" style="width: 80px;"></td>
      <td><input type="hidden" name="label_id[]" value="7"><input type="text" name="matchtext[]" style="width: 80px;"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I have this table like this 
id | termin_id | label_id | text 
 and here I have y controller

```
foreach($request['label_id']  as  $row){
    if($row == 1){
      $rowAnswer =  Label::create([
                          'appoitment_id'   =>  $appointment->id,
                          'text'          => $row
                        ]);
    }
    }
```

Comment: How to continue what?

Comment: Saving these records  on that table on label_id 1, 1, 1 .. and the text

Comment: Saving them where?

Comment: We are always glad to help and support new coders but ***you need to help yourself first. :-)*** After [**doing more research**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Comment: Are you submitting this data to a route that hands it off to that controller method?  Is it failing at some point before or while storing data?  Whats the error if so.

Comment: The code is not clear to make it correct, where is $appointment variable defined and how many tables do you have to save this data ?